# how to sum how many days from text fields in the 3rd textbox using datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

i have the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Sum Of Total Days</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function sum() {
datepickerln1 = $( "#datepickerln1" ).datepicker().value;
datepickerln2 = $( "#datepickerln2" ).datepicker().value;

document.getElementById('#total').value = parseFloat(datepickerln2) - parseFloat(datepickerln1) +1;
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Date 1: <input name="datepickerln1" id="datepickerln1" type="text" onblur="sum()"/></p>
<p>Date 2: <input name="datepickerln2" id="datepickerln2" type="text" onblur="sum()"/></p>
<input name="total" id ="total" type="text" readonly />

</body>
</html>
```

it is not doing sum of the total days when i put the date using datepicker in Date 1 & Date 2.

Please help

thanks

Comment: jQuery usually uses `val()` not `value`.

Comment: thanks for your response. i did as follows:
<script>

$(function sum() {
datepickerln1 = $( "#datepickerln1" ).datepicker().val();
datepickerln2 = $( "#datepickerln2" ).datepicker().val();

document.getElementById('#total').val() = parseFloat(datepickerln2) - parseFloat(datepickerln1) +1;
});

</script>

nothing happened same as before????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me point out the mistakes in your code and later a JSFiddle.

(A) Here are the few **mistakes** you made in your code:

1) first **initialize** the datepicker to your elements.

```
$( "#datepickerln1" ).datepicker();
$( "#datepickerln2" ).datepicker();
```

2) You can't get the value like this `$( "#datepickerln1" ).datepicker().value;`

After initialization, it should be like

```
$( "#datepickerln1" ).val();
$( "#datepickerln2" ).val();
```

3) `document.getElementById('#total').value`, there is no need of `#` here.

simply like

```
document.getElementById('total').value = 'your value';
```

or

```
$('#total').val('your value');
```

4) You can't get the **dateDifference** easily like this

```
parseFloat(datepickerln2) - parseFloat(datepickerln1) + 1 //WRONG
```

Correct way is

```
Math.floor((datepickerln2.getTime() - datepickerln1.getTime()) / 86400000) //RIGHT WAY
```

---

(B) You need to check this thread regarding [**dateDifference in datepicker**](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-datepicker-difference-between-two-date)

With the help of this thread, I have updated your code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selector = function (dateStr) {
        var d1 = $('#datepickerln1').datepicker('getDate');
        var d2 = $('#datepickerln2').datepicker('getDate');
        var diff = 0;
        if (d1 && d2) {
            diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
        }
        $('#total').val(diff);
    }
    $("#datepickerln1").datepicker();
    $('#datepickerln2').datepicker();
    $('#datepickerln1,#datepickerln2').change(selector)
});
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/433d9/)

Comment: please one more thing if u can help... if the totalno of days are 30 i want to count that how many fridays are in this month 4 or 5 and minus the fridays from 30 days..??????????????????

Comment: @usman610 check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18381346/1671639 you will get an idea.

Comment: i tried but i can't plz do it with the my code?

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selector = function (dateStr) {
        var d1 = $('#datepickerln1').datepicker('getDate');
        var d2 = $('#datepickerln2').datepicker('getDate');
        var diff = 0;
        if (d1 && d2) {
            diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000) +1; // ms per day
        }
        $('#total').val(diff);
    }
    $("#datepickerln1").datepicker();
    $('#datepickerln2').datepicker();
    $('#datepickerln1,#datepickerln2').change(selector)
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Did you alert the values and check if you are getting the values? The datepickers have not been assigned to the jquery `datepicker`. Do this first:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepickerln1" ).datepicker();
  $( "#datepickerln2" ).datepicker();
});
```

And use `document.getElementById('total').value` instead of `document.getElementById('#total').value`